# Sources of geolocated Tweets

Tags: data, twitter

Are there any publicly available sources of geolocated Tweets?

I'm aware that one can collect them on their own, but was wondering if there is something readily available to play with.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243125/twitter-data-archive) on Stack Overflow; however it's not focused on geolocation and the [first source](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/twitter7.html) mentioned there informs that:

> As per request from Twitter the data is no longer available.

[Second one](http://140kit.com/datasets) seems to be limited to specific tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want data for experimental purposes, the [VAST Challenge dataset from 2011](http://hcil.cs.umd.edu/localphp/hcil/vast11/index.php/dataset) has geolocated tweets. Specifically, the data for mini-challenge #1 (follow the *MC1 Materials* link) has the tweets. Please note the request to register in order to download the data.

Note that the coordinates in this dataset have been fabricated such that they're contained to an area roughly 150 square miles. The messages have been cleaned to remove actual names, and include some "fake" messages specific to the VAST challenge (messages indicating someone is sick). However, it is good for research and experimentation with geo-located tweets.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed might be interesting dataset to start with.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the entry from @underdark  where she explains how to get geolocated tweets  using curl.

http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/10/01/tweets-to-qgis/